# How to exit return loop in java?

Tags: java, android, return, calculator

I'm not new to programming per se, I have studied C# for quite a while now, but I haven't really done a lot of exercises by myself, I'm just now starting with java because I want to do Android apps and to test my newly acquired knowledge I wanted to do a basic console calculator, here's what I got so far:

```
package calculatorSource;

import java.util.*;

public class calculatorJava {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Select an operation");

        String choice = null;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(choice == null) {
            System.out.println("Type 'a' for adition, 's' for subtraction, 'm' for multiplication," + " 'd' for division, or 'mo' for module.");
            choice = input.next();
        }

        while(choice != null) {
            if(choice.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println(adition(0, 0));
                choice = null;
            } else if(choice.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println(subtraction(0, 0));
                choice = null;
            } else if(choice.equals("m")) {
                System.out.println(multiplication(0, 0));
                choice = null;
            } else if(choice.equals("d")) {
                System.out.println(division(0, 0));
                choice = null;
            } else if(choice.equals("mo")) {
                System.out.println(module(0, 0));
                choice = null;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Option not available, please try again.");
                choice = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static float adition(float n1, float n2) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float result;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        n1 = input.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        n2 = input.nextFloat();

        result = n1 + n2;

        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        return adition(result, result);
    }

    public static float subtraction(float n1, float n2) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float result;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        n1 = input.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        n2 = input.nextFloat();

        result = n1 - n2;

        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        return subtraction(result, result);
    }

    public static float multiplication(float n1, float n2) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float result;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        n1 = input.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        n2 = input.nextFloat();

        result = n1 * n2;

        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        return multiplication(result, result);
    }

    public static float division(float n1, float n2) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float result;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        n1 = input.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        n2 = input.nextFloat();

        result = n1 / n2;

        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        return division(result, result);
    }

    public static float module(float n1, float n2) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float result;

        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        n1 = input.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        n2 = input.nextFloat();

        result = n1 % n2;

        System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

        return module(result, result);
    }
}
```

I know it probably is not the best or more efficient calculator out there, but as I said, I just started with java and this is pretty much all I know so far, the program works, as I can make an addition, a division or whatever else I choose, but right after that I want it to give me the option of selecting a different operation, I put the "choice = null" right after the return but it doesn't not seems to be working, I've tried several stuff to this point, but I'm starting to think I may have misunderstood what return actually does, so I thought it would be better to turn to you guys for help.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Instead of `return adition(result, result);` in your `adition` method, return `result`. Otherwise you're just going to repeat the same method until the stack overflows. (Same for other methods also).

Comment: Your `while (choice != null) {` loop isn't necessary, as you always set `choice = null;`. Since you also don't otherwise change the value of `choice` in that loop, you may as well just remove the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
return adition(result, result);
```

in your `adition` method, return `result`.

Otherwise you're just going to repeat the same method until the stack overflows. (Same for other methods also).

---

Your `while (choice != null) {` loop isn't necessary, as you always set `choice = null;`. Since you also don't otherwise change the value of `choice` in that loop, you may as well just remove the loop.

---

There is no point in passing parameters into the `adition` (etc) methods, since you always overwrite them. Just declare them as local variables in those methods:

```
public static float adition() {  // No parameters
    // ...
    float n1 = input.nextFloat();
    // ... 
    float n2 = input.nextFloat();
```

Comment: I´ll just add here that there is no need for more then one `Scanner` instance, where every method creates a new one.

Comment: He need to change the Scanner loop to be able to go back up there after the operation, as asked. A static method is easier. **but right after that I want it to give me the option of selecting a different operation**

Comment: @AxelH yeah, that's exactly what I asked for, my calculator was already working (kind of) but nobody seems to have read that last part, I want it to back up but I have sincerely no clue how or where to put the instruction to go back, would you mind extending your answer a bit more? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are recursively calling all methods infinitely. choice = null is ok. it will terminate if you will correct your code :
Instead of

```
MethodaName(result, result);
```

just write

```
return result;
```

Also you need not pass any parameters if taking input from user in method itself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have misunderstood the return statement inside the function.
Whenever we call a function/method in java it should have a return type and the returned value should be what the function has to actually return after processing the arguments.

Hence in your case the addition function should be like this

```
public static float adition(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 + n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

    return result;
  }
```

Here the result variable is the processed value of your function for which it was created.

Where as in your case you were calling the same function in return statement and it was becoming a recursive function and in recursive function we always need a break statement to come out of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you could do.

1. If you want to run the operation just once then instead of

   ```
   return addition(result,result)
   ```

   use

   ```
   return result.
   ```

2 . Suppose you want to run the loop of addition until user says , he want to do some other operation, then use a global variable and suppose you add the condition when user enters -999 then you return.
Hence , in second case the loop of adition runs till user enters -999.

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculatorJava {
  private static Scanner input;
  static int flag = 1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Select an operation");

    String choice = null;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (choice == null) {
      System.out.println(
          "Type 'a' for adition, 's' for subtraction, 'm' for multiplication,"
              + " 'd' for division, or 'mo' for module.");
      choice = input.next();
    }

    while (choice != null) {
      if (choice.equals("a")) {
          flag = 1;
        System.out.println(adition(0, 0));
        //choice = null;
      } else if (choice.equals("s")) {
          flag = 1;
        System.out.println(subtraction(0, 0));
        //choice = null;
      } else if (choice.equals("m")) {
          flag = 1;
        System.out.println(multiplication(0, 0));
        //choice = null;
      } else if (choice.equals("d")) {
          flag = 1;
        System.out.println(division(0, 0));
        //choice = null;
      } else if (choice.equals("mo")) {
          flag = 1;
        System.out.println(module(0, 0));
        //choice = null;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Option not available, please try again.");
        choice = null;
      }
    }
  }

  public static float adition(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == -999){
        flag = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 + n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    if(flag==0)
        return result;

    return adition(result, result);
  }

  public static float subtraction(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == -999){
        flag = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 - n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    if(flag==0)
        return result;
    return subtraction(result, result);
  }

  public static float multiplication(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == -999){
        flag = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 * n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    if(flag==0)
        return result;
    return multiplication(result, result);
  }

  public static float division(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == -999){
        flag = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 / n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    if(flag==0)
        return result;
    return division(result, result);
  }

  public static float module(float n1, float n2) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    float result;

    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    n1 = input.nextFloat();
    if(n1 == -999){
        flag = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    n2 = input.nextFloat();

    result = n1 % n2;

    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
    if(flag==0)
        return result;
    return module(result, result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> To ask again

First, your while loop for the addition is not usefull, an IF could be enough, but useless to since you check the value before (in the first loop)

This is one possibility to loop on you code.

```
   boolean letDoMath = true;
   while(letDoMath ) { // aka while(letDoMath == true){
       while(choice == null) {
        System.out.println("Type 'a' for adition, 's' for subtraction, 'm' for multiplication," + " 'd' for division, or 'mo' for module.");
           choice = input.next();
       }
       //HERE YOU KNOW CHOISE ISN'T NULL BECAUSE OF THE WHILE LOOP, NO NEED TO CHECK AGAIN.

        if(choice.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println(adition(0, 0));
            choice = null;
        } else if(choice.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println(subtraction(0, 0));
            choice = null;
        } else if(choice.equals("m")) {
            System.out.println(multiplication(0, 0));
            choice = null;
        } else if(choice.equals("d")) {
            System.out.println(division(0, 0));
            choice = null;
        } else if(choice.equals("mo")) {
            System.out.println(module(0, 0));
            choice = null;
        } else if(choice.equlas("end"){
            letDoMath = false;
        }
    }
```

The boolean while give you the possibility to loop again an again until you input `end`. This in not perfect of course but this is a beginning. (And I didn't try or even write it in IDE so might contains errors.

> Operation methods error

As precise everywhere, your operation methods are recursive, addition call itself at the end. Remove the return addition(x,y) and just return the result of the addition you do.

Some improvment idea :

- Create a method to get a number an return it (usefull in every method).
- The best would be to ask number outside the operation to pass the value to the methods, not reading the scanner in the methods. (of course, you need to be sure of the choice value (actualy, you could ask for the number before the choice). And ask again ONLY if a operation has been done.